# Stoping scrolling of table heading <th> in a table within a div

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I have a html table inside div tag and I want to stop the table heading at the top of the div when scrolling the div. Position absolute is working fine for some browsers but IE does not suport this.

Please help...

Comment: I failed at understanding your question. Can you rephrase it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting a height on the div and scrolling the whole div, try putting all your non-heading table rows in a `tbody` tag, put a height on that, and scroll that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well , the straight forward answer to you is to create another table just above the div with just the header and the one inside with data and make the div scrollable. thus give the effect that heading is not scrolled!

I hope it helps!

Comment: but the combination will not well finished between the column name and column data. bcoz i have a large number of columns table.